# Cherry picking changes to specific files from a range of commits

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have a branch into which I accidentally merged other peoples changes a long time ago, and now hundreds of files show up on a pull request that are not mine.

I would like to create a separate branch into which I would like to cherry-pick changes to my own files over those several dozen commits, so that my new pull request only contains my changes.

I found out how to cherry pick commits, and how to cherry pick files from one specific commit, but *how do I cherry pick several files from a range of commits*?

Is there perhaps a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly, what you want to do first is cherry pick the range, i.e. `git cherry-pick --no-commit`. Then, remove the changes to your index with `git reset`. Then `git add` all of the files you want to commit, `git commit` those files, and finally `git checkout .` to get rid of the other local changes. This will result in a single, flattened commit that contains your changes.

Now, if instead what you want to do is include just those commits that have touched a particular set of files, you may want to take a look at an example given towards the bottom of [this page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) that uses `git rev-list` to feed a list of all commits that have touched a particular filespec to `cherry-pick`. So if, for example, all your files were in `mydir`, something *like* `git rev-list --reverse master -- mydir | git cherry-pick --stdin` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a single commit that you used to merge in, that you can avoid, then use [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) to skip the merging commit.

```
-----origin/foo-------A----------------------------B----C----D
                      (where you merged in)        (commits on top of that)

  AFTER REBASE

-----origin/foo-------B'----C'----D'
                      (your commits, skipping A)
```

If instead your changes (`B`, `C`, and `D` above) actually touch the files you're trying to avoid, you'll need to use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to rewrite those commits and avoid changing those files. Using the `--tree-filter` command, you can reset the part of each tree that you don't want to touch.